# Laravel Carbon change date to specific data

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

How to change f.e. only month and day in existing date variable(object ?)?

I've got date type fields in db:

```
$table->date('start');
$table->date('end');
```

And then I want in blade view change according to special conditions.

```
@if (Carbon\Carbon::parse($date->start)->month < Carbon\Carbon::parse($date->end)->month && Carbon\Carbon::now()->month != Carbon\Carbon::parse($date->start)->month)
@php
    $date->start = date('Y-m-d', '05');
@endphp
@endif
```

Above code changes the date to something like `"1970-01-01"`. The year could stay as it is stored in current variable, but I need to know how change only month and day of current date.

For example if I check the current date month isn't equal to the variable, then I change the date to current month.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with setters and `format` (method inherited from `DateTime`):

```
$date->start = Carbon\Carbon::parse($date->start)->startOfMonth()->setMonth(5)->setDay(13)->format('Y-m-d');
```

But I would warn about mutating values from inside the template, it sounds like an anti-pattern. Prefer to create an other variable like `$formattedDateStart` to keep things cleans and your original data unmodified.

Or you can simply call the `->format()` method only when you need it for display without actually storing this result anywhere.

EDIT: `->startOfMonth()` added to avoid trouble if the current day is not available in the chosen month.

Comment: It's only used for displaying data in calendar - coloring correct boxes. You talking about whole date, but I need only month or day to modify..

Comment: ->startOfMonth()->setMonth(5)->setDay(13)